# Handle rest template errors

Tags: java, spring

I developed a service, using resttemplate and using this service(clientproject) in another project(server), I am trying to throw the exception from resttemplate and handle at server project,but it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
public class UserService{

    public long createUser(Long servcieId){
     long userId =0L;
    try
    {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
         userId = response.getBody().getUser().getId();
    }
    catch(RestClientException e){

        throw e;
    }
    return userId;
    }
 }
```

Here is my service code:

```
public Long createUserInPortal(Long serviceId){

    try
        {
        Long userId=userService.createUser(serviceId);
        }
        catch(RestClientException e){
         if(e instanceof HttpStatusCodeException){
            String errorResponse=((HttpStatusCodeException)e).getResponseBodyAsString();
            logger.error("the error in user service is:"+errorResponse);
        }
}
```

I am getting the following error,"resulted in 422 (Unprocessable Entity); invoking error handler".
I am trying to see the response string in the catch block but it is not reaching this catch block.

Answer (score 0):

well may be its getting inside catch block but gets filtered by

`if(e instanceof HttpStatusCodeException){`   condition

May be e instance is not of type HttpStatusCodeException there are other possibilities like

```
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        success = false;
        Log.e(TAG, command+" was rejected for URL: "+url, e);
        resultCode = e.getStatusCode().value();
        response = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
        success = false;
        Log.e(TAG, command+" could not be completed for URL: "+url, e);
        resultCode = e.getStatusCode().value();
        response = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
        if (attemptsLeft > 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, command+" failed I/O, retrying.", e);
            return simplePut(baseUrl, url, b, command, payload, attemptsLeft);
        }
        success = false;
        Log.e(TAG, command+" failed I/O for URL: "+url, e);
        resultCode = 499;
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        success = false;
        Log.e(TAG, command+" failed for URL: "+url, e);
        resultCode = 599;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.shall I change the catch block in userservice?how to throw the exception in userservice.